# Reading csv data to array and perform operation

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I am trying to operate on csv data. [this is the csv file][1]

[1]: http://pastebin.com/MzLmQtye. I have to get the subtracted result of MxT and MnT.

```
    var fs = require('fs'),
    fileName = "weather.csv",
    bufferString;
var arr = new Array();


fs.readFile(fileName, "utf8", function(err, data) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    bufferString = data.toString();
    arr = bufferString.split('\n');
    //arr = arr.split(',');
    console.log(arr[1][1]);
});
```

From the above code, I get comma as well on array data. The `split(,)`also gives `TypeError: arr.split is not a function` error. How to do this.

I think best idea for me is to create object like this:

```
1:{
    max:""
    min:""
}
2:{
    max:""
    min:""
}
```

This would make it easy to do the subtraction operation. How to do this? I got puzzled. Please mention if I am not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over each line and split with comma. So following logs all MxT and MnT values to console:

```
fs.readFile(fileName, "utf8", function(err, data) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    bufferString = data.toString();
    arr = bufferString.split('\n');
    var line;
    for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
          line = arr[i].split(',');
          console.log(line[1]); // MxT
          console.log(line[2]); // MnT
    }
 });
```

Comment: Again, I could not figure out how to get the day, mxt and mnt on array. I did this: `type[i]=line[0][i];
          max[i]=line[1][i];
          min[i]=line[2][i];` I hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [fast-csv](https://www.npmjs.org/package/fast-csv) for this rather than writing your own parser.

```
var csv = require('fast-csv');
var items = [];

csv.fromPath('weather.csv', {
        headers: true
    })
    .on("data", data => {
        items.push(data);
    });
```

You will then have all the data you need in the items array, so you can do your subtractions like this.

```
items[0].MxT - items[0].MnT;
```